# Module not found in multi-folder Python package

Tags: python-2.7, package

I am trying to create a test package with multiple nested directories in Python 2.7, but it's not working. My directory structure is

```
testpack\
    setup.py
    testpack\
        __init__.py
        vspecial\
            __init__.py
            functions.py
```

where `setup.py` contains:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(name='testpack', packages=['testpack'])
```

The outer `__init__.py` file is simply `import vspecial`. The inner `__init__.py` file is simply `import functions`

When I do `python setup.py install` I get no errors, but when I enter python and do `import testpack` I get:

`"...Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\testpack-0.0.0-py2.7egg\testpack\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named vspecial`

I'm using Anaconda2 on Windows. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that in my `__init__.py` files, I should write relative imports: `from . import vspecial`.

And in the `setup.py` I should write `packages=find_packages()`